# Why can't I extend my monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am running on Windows 10. I have two 24 inch, 1080 monitors (one is the HP 24w, I can't remember what the other one is) I have a GTX 660 for my graphics card. I am using a hdmi splitter to connect both the monitors but it is not working.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: You may be exceeding the bandwidth for your HDMI cable. Does it work if you lower the resolution for both monittors to 720p? if that works, you probably need one or more new hdmi cables or your splitter may not be sufficient.

Comment: I am having the same problem here. I would guess that it has to do sth with the power supply of the monitor. Try powering the second monitor directly through the wall socket(not through CPU wire).